# JQuery: Transform and appendTo()

Tags: jquery

Alright, I have this function which is executed the moment a user drop's a div to a table.

```
function execCardDrop( $droppedCard )
{
    $droppedCard.appendTo(boardTable()); //Board table return's the table's id...
}
```

$droppedCard is the actual div, now before appending I would need to transform it as a td cell item so that the table add's it properly.

Now what are my options? Should I re-construct the item by getting it's values in another function or could I just wrap it in  before appending?

Comment: What exactly are you collecting from the dropped div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap it before appending. And if that causes any quick weird visual effect (very unlikely because the JS should run quickly enough), you could hide it first, wrap the clone, append it, and then show it again. For example

```
$droppedCard.hide().wrap('<td>').appendTo(boardTable()).show();
```